# I have a code that has a score counter that keeps repeating itself

Tags: python

I have a homework task that was to create a quiz. It had to contain a list of a pre-defined function. I am very new to python and coding and can only just understand the basics. In my quiz, I have a counter that keeps track of questions wrong and right and displays them at the end of the quiz. Currently, the summary repeats itself counting down to the right answer. I'm very confused and the quiz is due tomorrow. If anyone has a simple score counter I can either replace mine with or can help fix mine it would be much appreciated :)

I have looked over the code but can't determine the cause as I'm very new

```
k = 1 
while k==1:
#asks user a question
  print("Q10 - When was the first ever official Formula 1 race?\n1:1850 2:1950 or 3:Yesterday")
  q1 = input ("\n")
  intcheck(q1)
#correct answer
  if q1 == "2":  
    r.append(1)
    print("Congrats you got it correct\n")
#wrong answer
  else:  
    w.append(1)
    print("Tough luck, you got that one wrong!")

# score counter
while len(r) > 0:
  resultr += 1
  r.remove(1)
while len(w) > 0:
  resultw += 1
  w.remove(1)

#final scoreboard
  print ("===============================================")
  print ("----------------End Game Summary---------------")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ("You got",resultw,"wrong and ",resultr," correct")
  time.sleep(3)
  print ("              !Thanks for playing!             ")
  print ("===============================================")
```

Comment: It seems that your indents are off. Yours are 2-spaced and usual Python is 4-space. It seems that your summary printing is inside the last `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're new to python, I will introduce you a little bit to the Object-oriented programming...

```
import time

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers, solution):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.solution = solution
    def ask_question(self):
        print(self.question)
        for ix, rep in enumerate(self.answers):
            print(ix, ':', rep)
        user_rep = int(input())
        if user_rep == self.solution:
            print("Congrats you got it correct")
            return 1
        else:
            print("Tough luck, you got that one wrong!")
            return 0


question_10 = "Q10 - When was the first ever official Formula 1 race?"
anwers_10 = ['1850', '1950', 'Yesterday']
solution_10 = 1

questions = [(question_10, anwers_10, solution_10)]

right, wrong = 0, 0
for q in questions:
    quest = Question(q[0], q[1], q[2])
    user_rep = quest.ask_question()
    if user_rep == 1:
        right += 1
    else:
        wrong += 1


#final scoreboard


print ("===============================================")
print ("----------------End Game Summary---------------")
time.sleep(0.5)
print ("You got",wrong,"wrong and ",right," correct")
time.sleep(3)
print ("              !Thanks for playing!             ")
print ("===============================================")
```

You just have to create each question like this :

```
question_10 = "Q10 - When was the first ever official Formula 1 race?"
anwers_10 = ['1850', '1950', 'Yesterday']
solution_10 = 1
```

And then to add each question to the `questions` list before the loop.

Fell free to ask any question !

Comment: thanks for a speedy reply however ive had a massive facepalm moment. Turns out the summary was indented in by one and was apart of the loop above it...

Comment: however i do really appreciate the help even if i only understand half of it

Comment: If you want to learn python, Object-oriented programming will become quickly very useful. It's a way to create objects (like the object question here), that you can use later. I would suggest that you read documentation on this subject (here for example : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects)

Comment: It takes 10 minutes to understand the basics, and it is an essential step on every developer way

Answer (score 0):

The following code could a baseline:

```
import time

question_list = ["Q1 blabla", "Q2 blala", "Q3 blabla"]
size_question_list = len(question_list)
answer_list = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"]

correct_answers = []
for k in range(size_question_list):
    #asks user a question
    print(question_list[k])
    q = input ("your answer : ")

    if q == answer_list[k]:
        # Right answer
        correct_answers.append(k)
        print("Congrats you got it correct\n")
    else:
        # wrong answer
        print("Tough luck, you got that one wrong!")

#final scoreboard

print ("===============================================")
print ("----------------End Game Summary---------------")
time.sleep(0.5)
print ("You got",size_question_list - len(correct_answers),"wrong and ",len(correct_answers)," correct")
time.sleep(3)
print ("              !Thanks for playing!             ")
print ("===============================================")
```

Comment: I think the answers are different for each question and are meant to be displayed.

Comment: big thank you, found the real problem was just one indent made it a loop so that shows how new i am. appreciate the help though :)